# Give away code and complete ownership to someone

Tags: licensing

I want to give an application's source code and complete ownership for it to a company.

They are worried I will be asking for money later if they are using it. I do not want to make it open source. Is there any way to give ownership to them so they aren't worried about using it?

Comment: You can not always give complete ownership. Some rights are not able to pass to another person even if you want. That is by law and can differ between countries / legislations. It often works best if you just write down what you want, what the other party wants and that you are both ok with that. At least that is a start, bring that to your lawyer and she should be able to write it up in legal code.

Comment: Also it is not always possible to give something away without getting something in exchange. But those are all legal topics. Common sense dictates that you should not give up all rights because it might not be healthy for you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a legal contract mentioning that you won't sue and that they have all right. and sign it.

Comment: it sounds like what I need but I don't have any idea what to write in that document such that it makes it legal

Comment: there are thousands of different contracts out there, you can use this one as a template:

http://www.nearinc.com/pubs/draftsla_us.pdf



in any case, if you are doing it this way (which is the right way :) ), you should at least consult with a lawyer, to make sure for example, that you aren't getting sued by the company if something doesn't work in your code.

Comment: thanks for the link. suing me after giving the source code for free would be 'hilarious'.